# Why does every operator that commutes with $\hat{H}$ have an inverse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, group-theory, commutator

I was reading  M.S. Dresselhaus, [*Applications of Group Theory to the Physics of Solids*](http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.734j/www/texts.html) ([PDF](http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.734j/www/group-full02.pdf)), and, in chapter 5, she defines the *group of Schrodinger Equation* as the group of all operators $\hat{P_R}$ such that
$$[\hat{P_R},\hat{H}] = 0$$
Where $\hat{H}$ is the hamiltonian operator. And, to verify that this set form a group, she simply states that

> "every symmetry operation $\hat{P_R}$ has an inverse $\hat{P_R}^{-1}$ and from physical considerations $\hat{P_R}^{-1}$ is also in the group."

**I can't understand this. Where is my guarantee that the operator $\hat{P_R}$ will necessarily have an inverse?** Is it implicit in the fact that $[\hat{P_R},H] = 0$? If it is, i can't seem to see how. Perhaps i am missing a few details from the theory.

Another thing is the fact that the inverse is in the group. Mathematically i can see this in the way she defined the group. But she talks about a "physical consideration". Could anybody give me a intuition of this?

Comment: Note that the zero operator commutes with the Hamiltonian. Elements of a group have inverses by definition, so if you are defining $P$ so that it is an element of the *group of Schrödinger Equation*, it either has an inverse or it is not an element of the group.

Comment: I mean, he defines the set of all operators that commute with the hamiltonian to be the "possible" elements of a group. My question is why all of these can be the elements of the group. Couldn't it be a few operators that commute with the hamiltonian, yet don't have an inverse?

Comment: @Vitor The point of Accidental's comment is that it's not actually true that all operators that commute with $H$ are elements of the "group of Schrödinger equation", since the zero operator commutes with $H$ yet clearly has no inverse. Hence, the group is simply defined to be *those* commuting operators that do have an inverse.

Comment: $P_{R}^{-1}$ exists because a symmetry must have an inverse, so it is linked to the representation of $R^{-1}$ on the space of bounded operators on a (complex, separable) Hilbert space.

Comment: It MUST be noted that Mildred Dresselhaus is  a woman (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mildred_Dresselhaus) and the OP should edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course not **every** operator that commutes with the Hamiltonian has an inverse; it is very easy to find counter-examples of this.

However, in the PDF you linked to, $P_R$ are special operators which the author calls "symmetry operators", and they perform operations such as rotations, reflections, translation or permutation, all of which definitely have inverses. An operator will not be a symmetry operator if it does not have an inverse; thus, the statement that every operator $P_R$ has an inverse is true simply by definition.

Furthermore, from physical considerations, if we have, for example, a Hamiltonian which is invariant under translations along a specific axis, and we can show that a particular translation leaves the Hamiltonian invariant, then of course translation in the opposite direction should also leave it invariant, since both are on the same axis. This is not a rigorous proof, but it is easy to prove it rigorously yourself, both for specific cases (e.g. translation) and in the general case using known properties of the commutator.